# Unable to update App.Config using ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

I am building a C# based DLL that will be used by another exe to launch the user application. The GUI is rich with lot of parameter/value type of settings. I need to save the settings of the GUI and load if needed by user. I am trying to use the App.Config to save in the below format. 
The load part is implemented as follows and tested with a sample element:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);

System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection appSettings = (System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("Test1");           

if (appSettings.Settings.Count != 0)
{
  string m_bits = appSettings.Settings["Key1"].Value;
}
```

But in the Save part I am using a similar approach like as below:

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);

System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection appSettings5 = (System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection)configuration.GetSection("Test1");

if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] == null)
{
  configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
}
else
{
  configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
}

configuration.Save();
```

I am getting an error that Section or group name 'appSettings' is already defined. Updates to this may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined.

Basically, I want to save config from GUI to APP.Config and load the same whenever user wants to? While doing so I want to just update the APP.Config and doesnt want to create/clear the existing contents.

Actually I wanted to know the below inputs. Please suggest

1. If this is right approach for Load/Save App.Config.
2. Should I use XmlDoc approach?

Thanks

Comment: A web server will usually not have permission to write its own files (security measure: if someone gets control they cannot replace the site). Even if you give permissions the ability to save config is rather built for local/roaming/application hierarchy of local interactive applications. Web Apps are better off using a database (of some type) for any state they need to maintain.

Comment: You should use a `XmlDoc` approach beacause of secutiry reasons. Use your app.config just to read.

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a standalone Windows application and not web application

Comment: What you want might be exactly [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx). This will save your settings on a per user basis.